# how to search in sql for multiple terms sql full text search

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to search name (Shyam Kishor Pachauri) from data base. if i enter string in text box like "shy kis pac". how can i do this in sql server with c#

thanks in Advance

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

`select * 
   from <table_name> 
  where <column_name> like 'Shy%Kis%Pac%'`

should do it.